# How to mandate a certain text phase in a textfield in swift

Tags: swift, swift3

How do I make sure my email field has text ending with @companyname.com
so it wont proceed if it ends with something like @gmail.com?

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.emailField.text != "" || self.passwordField.text != "" && self.emailField.text == //what do i put here?//
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `hasSuffix`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to use `hasSuffix(:)` to check for a particular suffix.

```
@IBAction func login(_ sender: Any) {
    if self.emailField.text != "" || self.passwordField.text != "" && self.emailField.text.hasSuffix("@companyname.com")
    {
    }
}
```